# Chrome suggest password closes my login form

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have normal login form and I will show him with hover effect on some icon.
Its OK. But but problem is that Chrome show password suggest on inputs and when I move over this Chrome suggest it will hide my login form. How to do it to prevent hide my form? Chrome Suggest password list is not html markup and I can not set display: block; to this suggest list.

I want to keep the password suggestion.

Comment: _"and I will show him with hover effect on some icon. Its OK."_ - no, that is probably _not_ okay, for any users with sensory or motor skill issues. Those are likely to have problems with this to begin with, when your approach requires them to keep the mouse cursor in a specific place - even without the password suggest issue. My suggestion: Don't sacrifice usability, over the designer's inflated ego. Make this require a _click_ instead of a mere hover to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe That's how it worked for me before and worked well. Now I would like to try another solution.

Comment: Yeah, operative keyword in there being "me" ...

Comment: I guess you should be able to mitigate the issue, if you also use [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) to make the form visible. Then it will stay visible, as long as the focus is on one of the form fields - which should be the case when the password suggestions show, I suppose.